# Excel: Get max value in specific row with row number retrieved by a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I should like to get the max value in a specified row in another worksheet, where the row number is retrieved by a formula.

I can call up the desired row number from the sheet called “Kur” by this formula:

```
 =MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0).
```

That specific formula gives me the number 23 but this number of course changes when B2 is changed. So the formula

```
 =MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0)
```

gives me the row number I want.

```
 =MAX(Kur!23:23)
```

works as expected and gives me the largest value in row 23 in the sheet called “Kur”. But I cannot figure out how to combine the two and to use the result from my formula

```
 MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0)
```

as a parameter for the MAX function. I have tried:

```
=MAX(Kur!MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0):MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0)) 
=MAX(Kur!MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0)&”:”&MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0))
=MAX(Kur!&MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0)&":"&MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0))
```

But with no success. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way is to reconstruct the address as text, then use the INDIRECT function to turn the text reference into an actual reference i.e.:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("Kur!" & MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0) & ":" & MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0)))
```

Unfortunately indirect references are volatile, meaning they will recalculate all the time, slowing down your workbook. An alternative non-volatile means is to use INDEX:

```
=MAX(INDEX(Kur!1:10000, MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0), 1):INDEX(Kur!1:10000, MATCH(B2,Kur!$A$1:$A$35,0), 256)
```

Where 10000 and 256 are the random large numbers for number of rows and columns but can be adjusted as you like, or made more general using COUNTA with another INDEX function to reference only existing data.